# Postfix forwarding is not working

Tags: postfix, forwarding

I used this tutorial for forwarding email to another email address on a test mail server and Gmail but it did not work.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-postfix-forward-email-to-another-account/

How can I find out what's the problem?

1. How can I figure it out if my mail was received on main server?
2. How can I find out what is my forwarding method problem?

Postfix log:

```
Sep  9 12:18:17 server postfix/sendmail[10080]: fatal: bad string length 0 < 1: setgid_group = 
Sep  9 12:19:23 server postfix/master[12006]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
Sep  9 12:28:24 server postfix/master[25885]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
Sep  9 12:30:40 server postfix/postfix-script[28876]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is not running
Sep  9 12:30:42 server postfix/postfix-script[28955]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is not running
Sep  9 12:31:13 server postfix/master[29748]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
Sep  9 12:31:14 server postfix/master[29936]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
Sep  9 12:32:03 server postfix/master[31197]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
Sep  9 12:34:01 server postfix/postdrop[2200]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 12:34:57 server postfix/master[3820]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
Sep  9 12:35:01 server postfix/postdrop[3967]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 12:35:07 server postfix/master[4205]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
Sep  9 12:38:02 server postfix/postdrop[7888]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 12:39:02 server postfix/postdrop[9301]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 12:49:01 server postfix/postdrop[22743]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 12:56:01 server postfix/postdrop[1193]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 12:57:01 server postfix/postdrop[2747]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 12:58:01 server postfix/postdrop[4245]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 13:26:01 server postfix/postdrop[11767]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 13:37:01 server postfix/postdrop[27388]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 13:38:01 server postfix/postdrop[28812]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 13:39:01 server postfix/postdrop[30206]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 13:52:01 server postfix/postdrop[15271]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 13:53:01 server postfix/postdrop[16820]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 14:04:02 server postfix/postdrop[32421]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 14:05:02 server postfix/postdrop[1492]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 14:08:01 server postfix/postdrop[5150]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 14:09:01 server postfix/postdrop[6297]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Sep  9 14:10:01 server postfix/postdrop[7659]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
```

Netstat for listening ports:

```
root@server:~# netstat -lnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18906/popa3d    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8554/nginx      
tcp        0      0 183.23.14.12:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26997/named     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26997/named     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8342            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2577/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31700/sendmail: MTA
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26997/named     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31700/sendmail: MTA
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2269/memcached  
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      8554/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      26997/named     
tcp6       0      0 :::8342                 :::*                    LISTEN      2577/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      26997/named     
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      2500/mysqld     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*                           2269/memcached  
udp        0      0 183.23.14.12:53         0.0.0.0:*                           26997/named     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           26997/named     
udp        0      0 183.23.14.12:123        0.0.0.0:*                           2202/ntpd       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           2202/ntpd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           2202/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                26997/named     
udp6       0      0 ee82::5247:5dfe:fa7:321 :::*                                2202/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                2202/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                2202/ntpd       
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9995     2214/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5401     2502/php-fpm.conf)  /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     161280317 31700/sendmail: MTA /var/run/sendmail/mta/smcontrol
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10078    2500/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     9587     404/udevd           /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6527     2270/acpid          /var/run/acpid.socket
```

after solve port 25 conflict and clear log file:

```
root@server:~# cat /var/log/mail.log
Sep 10 00:44:19 server postfix/master[12480]: terminating on signal 15
Sep 10 00:44:19 server postfix/master[15838]: daemon started -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
```

Comment: Could you post relevant sections from your postfix logs?

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek i add postfix logs

Comment: I petitioned to move this to unix.se.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek as you wish, but my problem not solved yet.

Comment: Log doesn't show any connect attempts. Make sure you are using the right mail server.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have 2 SMTPDs running.  Use `netstat -lnp` as root and look for whatever is listening on port 25 (local address column). Then turn that program off and try starting postfix again.

*Update*, I see the netstat now. If you look in the middle there, you see a line that says 127.0.0.1:25. This means sendmail is listening for local delivery. You should stop the sendmail service and disable it.

```
service sendmail stop
chkconfig sendmail off
```

Comment: i add `netstat -lnp`. check this out.